# why $\nabla f$ in constant along $\alpha$?

Tags: differential-geometry

let $\gamma$ be a gradient curve of $f$ corresponding to a $k-flow$ $\alpha$ that:
$$\alpha'(t)=k(t)(\nabla f)(\alpha(t))$$
$$\gamma(t)=\alpha(t)+f(\alpha(t))e_{n+1}$$
and let U be the unit normal vector to the graph $\mathcal{G}$ of curve that :
$$U=\frac{-\nabla f+e_{n+1}}{\sqrt{1+||\nabla f||^2}}$$
$\gamma$ is principal if and only if $U'$ and $\gamma'$ are proportional along $\gamma$. We have:
$$\gamma'=k\nabla f+k||\nabla f||^2$$
and if $q=1+||\nabla f||^2$ we can write $U=q^{-\frac{1}{2}}(-\nabla f+e_{n+1})$. Hence:
$$U'=\frac{-q'}{2q^{3/2}}(-\nabla f+e_{n+1})-\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}(\nabla f)'$$
Actually, we can tell that a curve is principal if any of the following equivalent conditions holds:

1) $U'$ and $\gamma'$ are proportional along $\gamma$.

2) $\nabla f$ and $(\nabla f)'$ are proportional along $\alpha$.

3) the direction of $\nabla f$, or equivalently of $\alpha'$, along $\alpha$ is constant.

Actually, my problem is that I cannoot prove the third part is equivalent to others! I mean I cannot go from 1 to 3 !

Comment: It is clear that 2) $\Rightarrow$ 3).

Comment: @Gribouillis How? even if I prove this one I can Prove 1 $\Rightarrow$ 3 because I can go from 1 to 2!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $(\nabla f)^\prime = \lambda(t) \nabla f$ for $t$ in some interval $I$, and let $t_0\in I$  be such that $\nabla f|_{t_0}\not = 0$ and $w$ be a  vector such that $w.\nabla f|_{t_0}=0$, then the scalar function $g(t) = w.\nabla f$ satisfies
$$
g^\prime(t) = \lambda(t) g(t)\qquad g(t_0) = 0
$$
This implies that $g(t) = 0$ for all $t\in I$.

It follows that $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane orthogonal to $\nabla f|_{t_0}$, hence the direction of $\nabla f$ is constant.

**Edit** The fact that $g(t) = 0 $ for all $t\in I$ is a well known fact from the theory of linear differential equations: to prove it, let $\Lambda(t)$ be an antiderivative of $\lambda(t)$ on $I$, and remark that
$$\left(g(t) e^{-\Lambda(t)}\right)^\prime = (g^\prime(t) - \lambda(t)g(t))e^{-\Lambda(t)} = 0$$
It follows that $g(t)e^{-\Lambda(t)}$ is a constant, but this constant is $0$ because $g(t_0)= 0$. Hence $g(t) = 0$.

**Edit2** It occurs to me that this gives a simpler proof of the initial result:
$$\big(\nabla f(t)\big)^\prime = \lambda(t) \nabla f(t)\Longrightarrow \big(e^{-\Lambda(t)}\nabla f(t)\big)^\prime = 0\Longrightarrow\nabla f(t) = e^{\Lambda(t)-\Lambda(t_0)}\nabla f(t_0)$$

Comment: Actually this proof doesn't work! Why $g(t)=0$ for all $t\in I$ ?

Comment: See my edit above.